# Expresión regular en JavaScript que valide números enteros separados por comas

Tags: javascript, regex

Necesito una expresión regular en `JavaScript` para validar una entrada como esta:

`5461500,3256990012,8122715,3148419530,[...]`

- Debe validar números *solamente* de siete o diez dígitos
- Los números de diez dígitos *siempre* deben empezar por 3
- No deben existir letras, espacios, ni caracteres distintos de las comas que separan los valores
- No importa que haya números de siete o diez dígitos consecutivos o que solo haya de alguna de estas longitudes

Estoy utilizando esta expresión, pero es insuficiente:

`/^(\d+\,?)+$/`

Efectivamente, restringe todo lo que no sea número o coma (,). Pero todavía necesito que, si son números, tengan longitud de siete o diez dígitos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Podrías validar lo que buscas utilizando la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/^(3\d{9}|\d{7})(,(3\d{9}|\d{7}))*$/
```

Explicación:

- Para validar 10 dígitos empezando con 3 usamos: `3\d{9}`
- Para validar 7 dígitos usamos: `\d{7}`
- Para validar uno u otro caso usamos `|`, es decir, `(3\d{9}|\d{7})`
- Para validar que además pueda tener cero o más veces, coma y lo mismo que antes usamos: `(,(3\d{9}|\d{7}))*`

<kbd>[Demo](https://regexr.com/4m294)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente. Infalible.

Answer (score 4):

Una posible solución podría ser:

```
/^((\d{7}|3\d{9})(,(?=\d)|$))+$/
```

Aquí más detallada:

```
^(
    (
        \d{7} | 3\d{9}
    )
    (
        ,(?=\d) | $
    )
)+$
```

El segundo grupo está formado por múmeros de 7 dígitos o por números de 10 dígitos que empiezan por 3.

El tercer grupo está conformado por una coma seguida por un dígito (que no consume caracteres porque se esta usando [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) o por un final de línea

Todo esto está contenido en un grupo que puede repetirse una o más veces.

[Aquí](https://regex101.com/r/j5iVQ4/2) puedes comprobar diferentes patterns con esta expresión.

Answer (score 1):

Hola esta expresión cubre los criterios que solicitas:

```
/^((3\d{9})|(\d{7}))(,((3\d{9})|(\d{7})))*$/
```

Nota las secciones:

- 10 dígitos empezando por 3: `(3\d{9})`
- 7 dígitos: `(\d{7})`
- Si hay más números deben separarse solo por comas: `,...`

UPDATE: Puedes quitar algunos paréntesis en función de lo que no necesites capturar para referencia.